# Cannot find POI via google-places-api that can be found on google-maps and google-plus

Tags: google-maps, google-plus, google-places-api

I am trying to find a specific listing via the google-maps-places API, but I don't get any results. This is strange to me, as there is a Google+ page and also a google-maps entry.

Let's take a look at the links:

Google+:
https://plus.google.com/115673722468988785755/about

Maps: 
https://www.google.de/maps/place/AMWAY+Beratung+%26+Vertrieb+Haegebarth/@53.171976,9.465828,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47b106116fc69d69:0xe17811ab2780c71d

If I use the very same coordinates from the maps entry in my nearby search and use the name from the entry as the keyword (or location for what it's worth) the results is empty.

Places-API (with exact same coordinates):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=false&radius=2000&name=amway&location=53.171976,9.465828&language=de-DE&key=YOURKEY

I can of course imagine that the db for the Google+ POIs is a different one. But then again I don't see how the maps api does not find what I can find on the maps web app.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
map.places.nearbySearch({
  location: latLng,
  rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
  types: ['shop'], // optional
  name: "AMWAY Beratung & Vertrieb Haegebarth" // optional
},function(results, status){
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

    // The thing you need should be result[0]
    // console.log(results[0]);
    if (results[0].name == "AMWAY Beratung & Vertrieb Haegebarth") { // optionally check the type

      // You have your place :)

    }
  }
}
```

What a workaround! Rumours are that the Google Maps JS API v3.20 or later will allow us to trigger click events on POIs, thereby getting Place objects directly.